# How would I write a Vector class in Scala?

Tags: scala, vector

I'd like it to have the performance characteristics and include most of methods of Array[Double] but have additional extension methods such as dotProduct(), +, -, etc. I can write the additional extension  methods but need help on the implementation of the existing traits and the measures needed to get Array like performance.

```
class Vec(private val content:Array[Double]) extends WrappedArray[Double] {
  /* Trait implementation methods - incomplete */
  def array = content
  def apply(i:Int) = content(i)
  def length = content.length
  def update(i:Int, v:Double) = content.update(i, v)
  def elemTag = ???

  /* Example extension methods */
  def plus(that:Vec) = Vec(this.indices.map{ i => this(i) + that(i)})
  def elementProduct(that:Vec) = Vec(this.indices.map{ i => this(i) * that(i)})
  def sum = content.sum
  def dotProduct(that:Vec) = elementProduct(that).sum
}

object Vec {
  def apply(seq:IndexedSeq[Double]) = new Vec(seq.toArray)
}
```

Comment: Ok, and what's your exact problem, and what's your actual question? See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612729/how-does-scalas-vector-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want `Array[Double]` with some new methods then the best way to do this is to define an [implicit class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) that provides the additional methods. Something like this:

```
implicit class ArrayOps(vec: Array[Double]) {
  def plus(that: Array[Double]): Array[Double] =
    vec.indices.map(i => vec(i) + that(i))(collection.breakOut)

  def elementProduct(that: Array[Double]): Array[Double] =
    vec.indices.map(i => vec(i)*that(i))(collection.breakOut)

  def dotProduct(that: Array[Double]): Double =
    (vec elementProduct that).sum
}
```

You can then call `plus`, `elementProduct` and `dotProduct` on any `Array[Double]` and it will perform the appropriate operation from the `implicit class`.